# OOD : Who should create object from persistence layer?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

In my software, I have 5 main layers:

- UI
- CONTROLLER
- DOMAIN (business rules)
- PERSISTENCE
- MYSQL (db)

In which layer and to whom should I assign the responsibility to get the domain objects from the persistence layer? I decided to create a new partition in the domain layer, but doing so by the controller layer makes ambiguity about how to create domain objects.

I'm looking for an elegant solution for creating domain objects by taking them from the persistent state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should retrieve the objects from your persistence layer from the layer that has knowledge of the context / use-case.

In other words: in the layer where you've implemented your use-case, you should call the repository (or other persistence-layer objects) that can retrieve (or save) your objects from (or to) the database.
IMHO, that's the only correct thing to do.  It is the layer that has knowledge of the 'context' (the layer that knows the bigger picture) that also has knowledge of the 'lifetime' of your transaction.  That layer is responsible for your transaction management as well.

Comment: Thanks Frederik for your answer, I think you have totally right! So i could create a package Repository in domain layer and from Controller (that manages use-cases) i call Repository's classes to get and save model objects... is that right ?

Answer (score 0):

Well if your persistence layer is ready , There are some tools available which will create Classes from DB Schema,

One of them is NetBeans persistence plugin.

Now you can use any ORM tool for Domain Model [classes created from DB Schema] and actual DB.

Comment: In persistence layer i have classes that has factory method like create(Class<?> typeClass, String oid) that takes a type of class to create from storage with id equals to oid. I would access to this method from controller but withoud direct access.